# Remove all previous content from a DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-traversal

Let's say we have this HTML. The task is to make a function that should remove all previous content from the DOM element with `id="removeAbove"`

```
<nav class="navbar>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse">
      <form class="navbar-form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <p>This is a template</p>
    <p id="removeAbove"><a class="btn" href="#">Learn more</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tried `el.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = ""` but didn't solve the problem. Also tried using the parents. I am thinking about traversing the DOM tree and when the function finds the element with this ID, the previous items start deleting. But...no idea how this could be achieved with pure JS.

Comment: do you want to remove EVERYTHING in the parent BUT this element?

Comment: Do you want to remove all elements in the DOM that are before `removeAbove`?

Comment: Please show us your desired output..

Comment: Everything in the body except the element with the id="removeAbove" and the elements under it (if there are such) should be removed

Comment: @Alex, your explanation is still not 100% clear. Do you want A) to remove all child elements of the parent of the element with `id="removeAbove"` except the element with `id="removeAbove"`, or B) all siblings of the element with `id="removeAbove"` that are prior siblings to that element (i.e. leaving any siblings which are after that element, no such siblings exist in your HTML, so it is less clear than it could be)?  Your question would be much more clear if you [edit] it to add a sibling after `<p id="removeAbove">` and included the HTML you desire to be the result of this operation.

Comment: @Alex, From your comments below, it appears a third, and fourth possibilities may be what you desire: C) remove all elements from the `<body>` (note: *no `<body>` tag is shown in your HTML example*) except the element with `id="removeAbove"`. The `id="removeAbove"` element becomes a direct child of `<body>`; or D) remove all elements from the `<body>` except the element with `id="removeAbove"` and all of its direct ancestors (removing any descendants of those ancestors which are not ancestors of the element with `id="removeAbove"`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove **all** the elements *before* `removeAbove`, you'll need a loop:

```
removeAllBefore(document.getElementById('removeAbove'));
function removeAllBefore(el)
{
  var prevEl;
  while (prevEl = el.previousElementSibling)
    prevEl.parentNode.removeChild(prevEl);
  if (el.parentNode.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'BODY')
    removeAllBefore(el.parentNode);
}
```

This solution removes everything before the element, recursively, and stops at the `body` element.

[See it in action at plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/PbMn4LvamzBE3qEwTqEw?p=preview)

Comment: Well, nothing happens here. Put a console.log inside the While, but nothing prints in the console. It's like the while loop returns a false

Comment: so if there are any more issues, you'll have to post more info :)

Comment: Ignore my edit, Ven... I was finding it hard to comment.

Comment: In your example in plnkr try adding `<div><p>Some Text</p></div>` right after the body tag. Now, these elements won't be removed. But as my task says: all above should be removed

Comment: @Alex your question clearly states "revious content from a DOM element". So my answer removes *previous* content. Do you want to remove everything *around* instead?

Comment: @Ven He wants to remove the elements before the element that is container of `#removeAbove`.

Comment: @Ven https://plnkr.co/edit/eYlNP36xAXPDPTWqEz4v?p=preview Look at this. Now you should get what I meant. Your solution removes only the elements in `.container`

Comment: the last element should *not* be removed though. and indeed it's not

Comment: @Ven Sorry, in the example I gave u in the previous comment i made a mistake. The element below #removeAbove shouldn't be removed -> https://plnkr.co/edit/DP0gTby6bmWne64MOV2z?p=preview

Comment: @Ven in HTML doc `el.parentNode.tagName != 'BODY'` it's fine but in XHTML it's not ! because `tagName` will be `body`! You can use `.toUpperCase()` ;)

Comment: @Ven Looks like it works in your example. Will try it later in mine. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Np! Feel free to mark the answer as correct if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove everything in the body except the element with the `id="removeAbove"` please try this:

```
var el = document.getElementById("removeAbove");

(function removeAllChilds(el, protected) {
    //Make the protected elemnt the last in the list !
    el.appendChild(protected);
    //Remove all child but the protected
    while (el.firstChild && el.firstChild !== protected) el.removeChild(el.firstChild);
    //If we reachthe body we stop
    if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'body') return;
    //Call the function with the parent element
    removeAllChilds(el.parentElement, el);

})(el.parentElement, el);
```

**Demo:**

```js
var el = document.getElementById("removeAbove");

(function removeAllChilds(el, protected) {
 //Make the protected elemnt the last in the list !
    el.appendChild(protected);
    //Remove all child but the protected
    while (el.firstChild && el.firstChild !== protected) el.removeChild(el.firstChild);
 //If we reachthe body we stop
    if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'body') return;
    //Call the function with the parent element
    removeAllChilds(el.parentElement, el);

})(el.parentElement, el);
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
     <div>Some div</div>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse">
                <form class="navbar-form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
            <p>This is a template</p>
            <p id="removeAbove"><a class="btn" href="#">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```